# How to add data to POINT datatype in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, geometry, point

I have a POINT datatype column in my database.

I want to know how can I add data to it in the form of `(x, y)`.

I tried `` INSERT INTO `table_name` (my_col_name) VALUES (POINT(1,1)) `` and also

`` INSERT INTO `table_name` (my_col_name) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.809003 54.097834)',4326)) ``

But when I inspect to see if it inserted the data or not I see that it inserted gibberish value, like ć.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is just blob data. Depending on what you want to do with that point use one of those functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html